# SVG Filter animation issue

Tags: javascript, css, svg, gsap, svg-filters

I had some code written yesterday in situ on site yesterday and all was working fine. Without any change to the codebase today it has ceased to work.

```js
let $feTurb = $('#feturbulence');

        let timeline = new TimelineMax({
            repeat: -1,
            yoyo: true
        });

        timeline.add(TweenMax.to($feTurb[0], 20, {
            onUpdate: function () {
                var bfX = this.progress() * 0.005 + 0.020,
                    bfY = this.progress() * 0.05 + 0.1,
                    bfStr = bfX.toString() + ' ' + bfY.toString();
                $feTurb[0].setAttribute('baseFrequency', bfStr);
            }
        }), 0);
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.ripple {
        min-height: 380px;
        max-width: 850px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        filter: url('#turbulence');
        position: relative;
        z-index: 6;
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/4QFPZrY.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

svg {
      position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="ripple"></div>
                        <svg xlmns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                          <filter id="turbulence" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                            <feTurbulence id="feturbulence" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="1" seed="2" baseFrequency="0.01968375 0.1468375"></feTurbulence>
                            <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic"></feDisplacementMap>
                          </filter>
                        </svg>
```

https://codepen.io/webbist/pen/zWGNRZ

Example of working code in this codepen

I have no idea why on site it is now not working. I have been debugging all day to get to the route of this issue and am about to give up and try to recreate the effect some other way, any insight anyone can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into same origin restrictions for feDisplacementMap. If you remove that from your filter, it works just fine. You are not allowed to use a cross origin image as the input to a displacement map because of timing attacks.

(Chrome occasionally misses this and lets a cross origin go through - but it is incorrect behavior)

The easy fix is to convert that imgur origin image into an inline URI within the filter.

```
<div class="ripple">
  </div>
      <svg xlmns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
         <filter id="turbulence" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
          <feImage x="0" y="0 " width="400" height="400"  result="displace" xlink:href="data:image/png; etc etc. etc." - not including the full URI here it's way too big - "/>
          <feTurbulence id="feturbulence" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="1" seed="2" baseFrequency="0.01968375 0.1468375"></feTurbulence>
          <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B" scale="25" in="displace"></feDisplacementMap>
           </filter>
        </svg>
```

Comment: On the site it comes from a path on the same domain, no cross-origin issues, the example needed something uploaded to work, hence the imgur upload. So my issue isnt related to that.

I have been messing with it since and it appears to potentially be a z-index issue on site, I am still refactoring things and will post an answer if I do solve it.

Comment: That's really weird. when I switched over to the URI it rendered on firefox and chrome! Looks like I just triggered correct behavior by accident! Your sample code above does not render on Firefox as-is.

Comment: Pretty sure its just a GPU issue, the site is pretty performance heavy and I have yet to optimize :/ https://www.codeinthedark.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue, there are a lot of performance-hungry things on my site, to offset these to the GPU I have been using will-change, this on the elements I was filtering caused them to... well not render at all. 
I have refactored much of the code since to try and improve performance and have it all working now on site, however there is still a hunger for GPU rendering and as such the "ripple" elements using this svg filter fail to respect transition animation css when changing opacity's so probably need to implement the image in the SVG + add some FEAnimation to see if that improves things.

Failing that I will be recreating this effect using pixi.js on canvas.